# разделить строку на си

Tags: c

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как такое повторить на языке Си?

```
data = '1:2\n3:4';
sessions = data.split('\n');

for session in sessions:
    ck, sid = session.split(':')
    print(ck + ' : ' + sid ); 
# ck: 1, sid: 2
# ck: 3, sid: 4
```

Я набросал вариант, но он оказался не рабочим:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char orig[] = "1:2\n3:4";
    char *p_orig = NULL;
    char *p_orig2 = NULL;

    p_orig = strtok(orig, "\n");

    while (p_orig != NULL) {
        p_orig2 = strtok(p_orig, ":");

        while (p_orig2 != NULL) {
            printf("%s", p_orig2);
            p_orig2 = strtok(NULL, "\n");
        }

         p_orig = strtok(NULL, "\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

результат этого кода *12*

А нужно как в коде на питоне. Помогите, пожалуйста

Comment: попробуйте во внутреннем цикле `sscanf("%d:%d,p_orig,&var1,&var2)`

Comment: @DNS , дело в том, что эти разбитые данные нужно занести в массив, чтобы потом использовать

Comment: ну так вместо переменных в скааннере поставьте элементы массива

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если строка именно такая, из пар - то можно вот так:

```
int main()
{
    char orig[] = "1x2:2z3\n3cvb:4rew\n5456:6776654";
    for(char * s = strtok(orig,":\n");s;s = strtok(NULL,":\n"))
    {
        char ck[20], sid[20];
        strcpy(ck,s);
        if (!(s = strtok(NULL,":\n"))) break;
        strcpy(sid,s);
        printf("# ck: %s, sid: %s\n",ck,sid);
    }
}
```

Comment: то, что нужно. премного благодарен)

Comment: @ast только лучше используйте `strsep()`.

Answer (score 1):

Что-то типа

```
int main()
{
    char orig[] = "1:2\n3:4\n5:6";
    for(char * s = strtok(orig,"\n");s;s = strtok(NULL,"\n"))
    {
        int ck, sid;
        if (2 == sscanf(s,"%d:%d",&ck,&sid))
        {
            printf("# ck: %d, sid: %d\n",ck,sid);
        }
        else break;
    }
}
```

устроит?

Comment: да, спасибо.  )))

Answer (score 0):

[strtok](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok) использует статическую внутреннюю структуру для парсинга.

Поэтому для вложенного разбора на токены по разным разделителям нужно использовать `strtok_r()`
(по ссылке на strtok внизу manpage есть пример программы именно для strtok_r)

P.S.  используя эти функции надо  всегда помнить, что они необратимо калечат разбираемую строку.

Comment: и что же использовать вместо неё? есть альтернатива?

Comment: нужно свою функцию написать..

Comment: @ast, писал когда-то [strtos](https://pastebin.com/6XBP0KZH), можете попробовать

Comment: спасибо, попробую